# How to get messages by using Webhooks such as the Getupdeats method in the Bot Telegram Documentation?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, telegraph

I would like to create a telegram bot with Express JS and Telegraph JS and get messages from the user in the way
I created a host using ngrok

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf(config.get('Customer.BOT_CONFIG.TOKEN'))
const app = require('express')()

app.use(bot.webhookCallback('/https://c2b4-5-237-204-80.eu.ngrok.io'))
bot.telegram.setWebhook(`https://api.telegram.org/TOKEN/setwebhook?url=https://c2b4-5-237-204-80.eu.ngrok.io`)
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
  res.send('Hello World!')

})

app.listen(3000, (c) => {
    console.log('server is running on port 3000');  
})
```